# Navigation don't work correctly

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, record, navigation

With this code, I want the moment I click on the button the user moves to the account object (redirection from obj__c to account_c).

- obj__c  has a Master-Detail relation with the Account .
- When adding each record of obj__c , we indicate associated account .

I don't get any error but I know that there is a problem in my code because when I use in recordId an account id value, the redirection works correctly.

=> Apex

```
public with sharing class objClass{
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static obj__c MyMethode(Id objId) {
            return[SELECT id ,Account__r.id FROM obj__c WHERE id=:objId LIMIT 1];
        
}
}
```

=> JS

```
import { LightningElement, api , wire, track } from 'lwc';
import IdAccount_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/obj__c.Account__r.id'; 
import MyMethode from '@salesforce/apex/objClass.MyMethode ';
import { NavigationMixin } from "lightning/navigation";

export default class RedirectToPage extends NavigationMixin (LightningElement) {

    @api recordId;

    @wire(MyMethode,{ objId: '$recordId'}) acc;

    get MyId() {
        return this.acc.data  ? getSObjectValue(this.acc.data, IdAccount_FIELD) : '';        
    }

    navigateToAccountPage() {
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: this.MyId,       
                objectApiName: 'Account',
                actionName: 'view'
                 }
        });
   
    }

}
```

=> HTML

```
<template>  
    <div class="slds-box slds-theme_shade">  
      <lightning-button label="Back to Account" onclick={navigateToAccount}> </lightning-button>  
    </div>  
  </template>
```

Comment: What happens when you call the method this.MyId() instead of this.MyId? Also are you able to debug what is there in this.MyId?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava , I don't get any error and also I am not redirected to the page , the request is correct , I tried it in the inspector , but when I call it in the js it is not working , even if I used this.MyId() , I tried to debug but  don't get any thing

Comment: ok that simply means your getter is not called, how about using directly this.acc.data  ? getSObjectValue(this.acc.data, IdAccount_FIELD) : ''  in your recordId variable.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava , I tried to use  directly this.acc.data ? getSObjectValue(this.acc.data, IdAccount_FIELD) : '' in my recordId variable but don't work for me .

Comment: add a debug on that navigate function and let me know what you see in the logs?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava , when I clique on the button , I don't get any error in the logs , Status is Success

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141701/discussion-between-mohith-shrivastava-and-salesforce-dev98908).

Comment: @MohithShrivastava , ok , thank you

Answer (score 0):

Few issues I noted was your `onclick` calls a different method `navigateToAccount` and your JS method name is `navigateToAccountPage`.

But lets say we ignore this, I see your LWC class declaration missing `extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement)`

So your LWC should look like:

HTML:

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-box slds-theme_shade">
        <lightning-button label="Back to Account" onclick={navigateToAccountPage}> </lightning-button>
    </div>
</template>
```

JS:

```
/**
 * Created by Nagendra on 03-01-2023.
 */

import { LightningElement, api , wire, track } from 'lwc';
import IdAccount_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/AccountMaster__c.Account__r.id';
import MyMethode from '@salesforce/apex/AccountRedirectPage.MyMethode';
import { NavigationMixin } from "lightning/navigation";
import {getSObjectValue} from "@salesforce/apex";

export default class NavigatetoAccount extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api recordId;

    @wire(MyMethode,{ objId: '$recordId'}) acc;

    get MyId() {
        return this.acc.data  ? getSObjectValue(this.acc.data, IdAccount_FIELD) : '';
    }

    navigateToAccountPage() {
        console.log(this.MyId)
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: this.MyId,
                objectApiName: 'Account',
                actionName: 'view'
            }
        });

    }
}
```

And it should work fine.

Also apart from that no need to mention like this `Account__r.id`. YOu can replace this with `Account__c`, both in apex and in LWC.

[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation)

Comment: i tried your proposition but did not worked for me , even the console.log did not appear

Comment: I already executed this and its working fine. Where is your component located? Which page?

Comment: my component i put it in record page of obj__c and i want through the button navigate to Account object which has master detail relation with obj__c

Comment: Please check my html and JS, this works perfectly in a Record Page of `AccountMaster__c` object. Please check your method names. The `onClick` on your html is different that mine. Please verify if both the `onClick` method name is same as JS method name as `navigateToAccountPage`

Comment: I verified all this but still don't work for me